# How to make a list of most ordered item on database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, list, model-view-controller

I have a MVC like store.
I wish to make a list of the most bought items (in this case prints, because it's a print store).
I'm finding it very hard specially because I'm very new to php / mysql and specially to this MVC structure... I hope this isn't a bad question.

I have a **model.php**  like this :

```
 <?php

class model {

private $conn;

function __construct() {
    $server = "localhost";
    $login = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "printstore";

    $conn = new mysqli($server, $login, $pass, $db);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
}

function __destruct() {
    $this->conn->close();
}

function buildArr($result) {
    $arr = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($arr, $row);
    }
    return $arr;
}

}
```

a **controller.php**:

```
 <?php

 include 'model.php';

 class Controller {

 private $model;

function __construct() {
    $this->model = new model();
}


function home() {
    include 'views/home.php';
}

    }
```

a **index.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'controller.php';

define("BASE_URL", 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/printstore2/index.php/'); 

define("MAIN_BASE_URL", 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/printstore2/');

$controller = new controller();


include 'views/templates/header.php';

if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {  
$url = explode("/", $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']); 
$function_name = $url[1]; 
if (isset($url[1]) && $url[1] !== "") {
    if (isset($url[2])) {
        $controller->$function_name($url[2]); 
    } else {
        $controller->$function_name(); 
    }
} else {
    $controller->home();
}
} else {
include 'views/home.php';
}

include 'views/templates/footer.php';
```

And the view where I want to post the "Best Selling Prints":

```
 <div>

<h2>Top Prints</h2>
    <ol>
       <li>1st print most bought</li>
       <li>2nd</li>
       <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
```

Now, my database has a table called "print_for_sale" which has the print_id and the sale_id, where I can see how many of each prints has been bought.

[image: database]

How can I do this? I'm so lost!

I'm sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNT and GROUP BY
to get a list of all prints vs their sale count:

```
SELECT fk_print_id as printId, COUNT(print_for_sale_id) as saleCount
FROM print_for_sale
GROUP BY fk_print_id
ORDER BY saleCount DESC
```

that is, if i understood your table right.

Comment: Thank you! I should do that in the model, right? I'm confused as how to do that in mvc. What do I pass to the controller and to the view?

Comment: that's right, and to answer the rest of your questions http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mvc-for-noobs--net-10488

Comment: Yeah I did see that tut already! Still a bit lost...But thank you anyway. :)